# how to set the recyckerView layoutParams which nested by SwipeRefreshLayout outside it

Tags: android

I need to  get the `recylerview` its `layoutParams`  and set its `topMargin`,but  my `recylerview` is nested by a `swiperefreshlayout` outside it so when I get the `layoutParams` like this:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = mListView.getLayoutParams();
```

so there is no method like  `topmargin`  for the  `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`.
when I cast the `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` to `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams`  I got this method  but when i run my model it becomes error .if anyone can help me ,thanks very much